# How to clear Android app data in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm using Phonegap Build for my application. I wonder is there any way to clear ALL app data (not just localStorage or cache) in my app? I have some problems with relogin in my app for Android. When I do `localStorage.clear()`, it seems like Android doesn't clean data. I also tried to clean cache at that moment (using cordova-plugin-cache-clear plugin). But if I clean app data manually (in phone`s settings) it works perfectly. Otherwise I have conflicts when I try to login again, as if Android use some old previous data. Other platforms work ok.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.clear should do it (I've used it successfully).

Normally I don't use it though, as (obviously) it cleans out everything.

So, for individual credentials, options and such I use localStorage.removeItem.

There's no need to clear the cache. localStorage calls have immediate effect, at least from the app's point of view.

Without seeing the login code it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to clear App data for Android and iOS apps:

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-clear-data

Another way, is using [ionic framework](http://ionicn.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/). There is `$ionicHistory.clearCache()` which will clear app data.

Comment: Perhaps it can help (the plugin). I will try it if the problem appears again, now I don`t have possibility to come back to that problem. I know about ionic, but it`s hard to add framework to ready application.

Comment: The plugin is no longer relevant. It hasn't been updated for years and doesn't work now in the year 2022

Answer (score 0):

When change the code and run in borwser by

> cordova run browser

and haven't any change, then use:

> cordova build

and run again:

> cordova run browser